# Issues with @ in symbol names when linking with HDF5 for fortran

Tags: linker, fortran, hdf5, intel-fortran

I am having issues linking the HDF5 library with a solution in Visual Studio 2010, using Intel Fortran 11.1.

The specific error message is:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _H5F_mp_H5FOPEN_F@24 referenced in function _WRITE_HDF5_ARRAY_2D
```

This symbol should be in the hdf5_fortran.lib library, and inspecting the symbols in the hdf5_fortran.lib file, I find that it does indeed contain the symbol

```
00B 0000010A SECT1  notype ()    External     | _H5F_mp_H5FOPEN_F
```

Additional relevant information: I have checked that the linker does include the hdf5_fortran.lib file properly by inspecting the command line statements. In addition, misspelling the library file name reports a file-not-found error.

The code base is, due to several historical reasons, compiled with /names:as-is and /assume:nounderscore.

Now, without being an expert on linking symbols, it appears that the "decoration" @4 at the end of _H5F_mp_H5FOPEN_F@ conflicts with the defined symbol _H5F_mp_H5FOPEN_F, so the obvious question is: How can I get rid of this @4 in the symbol reference in my code, or alternatively are there other ways to go about this?

Comment: `_H5LIB_mp_H5OPEN_F` is different from `_H5F_mp_H5FOPEN_F`, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. In fact, it can't find several symbols, I just picked the wrong reference. I'll edit it, thanks!

Comment: ok, well, did you compile the HDF library with MS Visual Studio?